# Noise texture and vectors

Tags: texturing, shader-nodes

Why do we need to substract 0.5 from vector, "made" of *Noise* texture, for it to scale offset properly as shown in [this video](https://streamable.com/al9l65)?

Comment: Excuse me, could you please update the link to the video? I'd love to see it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid it got completely erased from Streamable. There's nothing I can do, sadly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to - it depends on what you want to achieve. First of all, the *Noise Texture* (if not modified by a *Color Ramp* or *Map Range* node for example), gives an evenly spread distribution of values between 0 and 1 either as a single grayscale value (the *Fac* output) or for each of the three color channels *Red*, *Green* and *Blue* (the *Color* output).

Since they are evenly distributed, the average value of the 0 to 1 range is 0.5, so either a medium grayscale single value of 0.5, or a medium gray with RGB = (0.5/0.5/0.5).

Let's say you have a flat plane and you use a *Noise Texture* as height map, than you don't have to subtract anything. In this case the height of your plane will have values from 0 to 1 and the average height is 0.5 - in this case you wouldn't mind.

A different thing is it (depending on what you're aiming for) if you want to distribute vertices, normals (or whatever you try to affect with the *Noise Texture*) evenly in **all** directions based on their original position to make it look random.

Since the texture only has positive values (0 to 1), the change in position will only work in +X, +Y and +Z direction, with an average of +0.5 in X, Y and Z.

So to make the original move either in positive **or** negative directions, you have to shift the *Noise Texture*'s original 0 to 1 range to a -0.5 to +0.5 range so that they are averaging around 0.

To achieve this, a simple solution is subtracting 0.5 on all X, Y, Z. Or for a one-dimensional grayscale value you could also use the *Map Range* node set to *From Min* = 0, *From Max* = 1 and *To Min* = -0.5, *To Max* = 0.5 for example.

I hope this helps, otherwise I'll try to make a sketch later.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!